# Find the largest number of natural numbers to put around the circle to have sum of all numbers: 800 and sum of remainders of adjacent numbers: 500

Tags: number-theory

`n` natural numbers were put around the circle. The sum of all numbers is equal to 800. For each pair of adjacent numbers, the larger was divided by the smaller with a remainder (e.g. if the adjacent numbers are 5 and 7 or 7 and 5 in any order, then we take 2 as a remainder and if the numbers are equal then the remainder is zero). The sum of all `n` such remainders is 500. What is the largest possible value of `n`?

It is straightforward though tedious to find the solution for 46 such numbers:

`1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 33, 64, 127, 253, 127, 64, 33, 17, 9, 5, 3`.

To get to that, start from the optimal numbers to get the maximal sum of remainders starting from the smallest number larger than or equal to 2 on the circle, call it `(a + 1)`. Then to maximize the remainders, the adjacent numbers must be: `(2 * a + 1)`, then `(4 * a + 1)`, then `(8 * a + 1)`, etc…, which produces an optimal value of `a = 1` and then a sequence: `2, 3, 5, 9, 17, 33, 65, 129, 257`. When put both ways around the circle: `2, 3, 5, 9, 17, 33, 65, 129, 257, 129, 65, 33, 17, 9, 5, 3`, that sequence produces the sum of the remainders: `S = 510` and the sum of all numbers: `T = 781`. We can then split the `2` and look at how can we adjust the numbers around 2 and 257 so that to decrease `S` by 10 while decreasing `T` by the largest possible number. Once this is done, we can put enough `1` between the `2`s to get `T` to 800 and that produces the answer above.

I wonder if it is possible to come up with a larger value of `n` and / or prove that this is the largest possible number. Wolfram chokes on such a problem. It does not give up, but it just simply does not come back. The solution above was found with a pen and paper.

Comment: Try alternating 1 and 2's

Comment: Alternating 1 and 2 would produce all remainders = 0. However, alternating `(a + 1)` and `(2 * a + 1)` and then solving for `n * a = 500`, `(3 * a +1) * n / 2 = 800` produces `a = 10` and `n = 50`, which means alternating 11 and 21 produces n = 50. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Why not 2 and 3 then